# What is bytes calldata _data?

Tags: solidity

What's the function and how is it used of `bytes calldata _data` in this contract function?

```
  /**
    Mint a batch of tokens into existence and send them to the `_recipient`
    address. In order to mint an item, its item group must first have been
    created. Minting an item must obey both the fungibility and size cap of its
    group.

    @param _recipient The address to receive all NFTs within the newly-minted
      group.
    @param _ids The item IDs for the new items to create.
    @param _amounts The amount of each corresponding item ID to create.
    @param _data Any associated data to use on items minted in this transaction.
  */
  function mintBatch(address _recipient, uint256[] calldata _ids,
    uint256[] calldata _amounts, bytes calldata _data)
    external virtual {
    require(_recipient != address(0),
      "ERC1155: mint to the zero address");
    require(_ids.length == _amounts.length,
      "ERC1155: ids and amounts length mismatch");

    // Validate and perform the mint.
    address operator = _msgSender();
    _beforeTokenTransfer(operator, address(0), _recipient, _ids, _amounts,
      _data);

    // Loop through each of the batched IDs to update storage of special
    // balances and circulation balances.
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _ids.length; i++) {
      require(_hasItemRight(_ids[i], MINT),
        "Super1155: you do not have the right to mint that item");

      // Retrieve the group ID from the given item `_id` and check mint.
      uint256 shiftedGroupId = (_ids[i] & GROUP_MASK);
      uint256 groupId = shiftedGroupId >> 128;
      uint256 mintedItemId = _mintChecker(_ids[i], _amounts[i]);

      // Update storage of special balances and circulating values.
      balances[mintedItemId][_recipient] = balances[mintedItemId][_recipient]
        .add(_amounts[i]);
      groupBalances[groupId][_recipient] = groupBalances[groupId][_recipient]
        .add(_amounts[i]);
      totalBalances[_recipient] = totalBalances[_recipient].add(_amounts[i]);
      mintCount[mintedItemId] = mintCount[mintedItemId].add(_amounts[i]);
      circulatingSupply[mintedItemId] = circulatingSupply[mintedItemId]
        .add(_amounts[i]);
      itemGroups[groupId].mintCount = itemGroups[groupId].mintCount
        .add(_amounts[i]);
      itemGroups[groupId].circulatingSupply =
        itemGroups[groupId].circulatingSupply.add(_amounts[i]);
    }

    // Emit event and handle the safety check.
    emit TransferBatch(operator, address(0), _recipient, _ids, _amounts);
    _doSafeBatchTransferAcceptanceCheck(operator, address(0), _recipient, _ids,
      _amounts, _data);
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`calldata` is a special data location that contains the function arguments, only available for external function call parameters. Calldata is a non-modifiable, non-persistent area where function arguments are stored, and behaves mostly like `memory`.

If you can, try to use `calldata` as data location because it will avoid copies and also makes sure that the data cannot be modified. Arrays and structs with `calldata` data location can also be returned from functions, but it is not possible to allocate such types.

Now as for `bytes`: It's just a variable type that holds a sequence of bytes from 1 to up to 32.

And as for the actual parameter, and it's meaning in the contract, I found the contract that you're referring to, and its additional data with no specified format, it seems also to be an optative parameter.

#### Note:

Prior to version 0.6.9 data location for reference-type arguments was limited to `calldata` in external functions, `memory` in public functions, and either `memory` or `storage` in internal and private ones. Now `memory` and `calldata` are allowed in all functions regardless of their visibility.

Prior to version 0.5.0 the data location could be omitted and would default to different locations depending on the kind of variable, function type, etc., but all complex types must now give an explicit data location.

For more details on `calldata`, go [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/types.html#data-location).

For more details on `bytes`, go [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays).

For more details on the actual contract, go [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/presets).